# vincular HTML con archivo PHP

Tags: php, html, html5, formularios

```
if (
  !isset($_POST["nombre"]) ||
  !isset($_POST["email"]) ||
  !isset($_POST["mensaje"])
) { 
  die (
    "Es necesario completar todos los datos del formulario"
  ); 
} 
$nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$mensaje = $_POST["mensaje"];
$smtpHost = ""; 
$smtpUsuario = "@laserbell.com.ar"; 
$smtpClave = ""; 
// $emailDestino = "@gmail.com"; 
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); 
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; 
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; 
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->CharSet = "utf-8"; 
$mail->Host = $smtpHost;
$mail->Username = $smtpUsuario; 
$mail->Password = $smtpClave; 
$mail->From = $email; 
$mail->FromName = $nombre; 
$mail->AddAddress($emailDestino); 
$mail->Subject = "Contacto Laserbell web"; 
$mensajeHtml = nl2br($mensaje);
$mail->Body = "{$mensajeHtml} <br /><br />Formulario Laserbell<br />"; 
$mail->AltBody = "{$mensaje} \n\n Formulario contacto Laserbell"; 
$estadoEnvio = $mail->Send(); 
if ($estadoEnvio){
  echo "
    <h1>Mensaje enviado, ¡Gracias por contactarme!</h1>"; 
  echo "
    <p>Tu mensaje se ha enviado correctamente.</p>
    <h2>Importante</h2>
    <p>Revisa tu bandeja de SPAM, en ocasiones mis respuestas quedan ahí. </p>";
} else { 
  echo "Tu mensaje no se ha enviado. Intenta de nuevo."; 
}
```

con que método se puede vincular un archivo html desde un php enviado por medio de un formulario de contacto?

el sitio es el siguiente  [Sitio de muestra](https://laserbell.com.ar/)

Comment: Por favor no comentes tu pregunta para complementarla  puedes dar click en editar ya si complementar tu pregunta.

Comment: No uses enlaces externos para mostrar el código, pues con el tiempo se pierden y las preguntas pierden el sentido.  Pon un [example] válido para que podamos ayudarte mejor, gracias.

Comment: Y recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta para agregar o modificar lo que necesites de ella pulsando sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la misma. No uses los comentarios para agregar código, gracias.

Comment: Nose como editar bien la pregunta.

Comment: Cuando pulsas sobre el enlace "Editar" que aparece debajo de la misma deberia aparecerte tu misma pregunta en modo edición para que la puedas modificar.  Si acaso tira el raton arriba o abajo para ver donde esta el cuadro de edición, pues mientras editas cambios en dicho cuadro entonces, más abajo, vas viendo como va quedando lo que editas, y quizas eso te confunde.

Comment: Si si claro eso lo vi, pero cada ves que quiero agregar un fragmento de codigo me tir error, quiero pegar lo que realice en php.

Comment: ¿y que error te da?  Si estas pegando texto deberia dejarte hacerlo, y una vez pegado te permite seleccionarlo y marcarlo como un bloque de código pulsando sobre el boton `<>`

Comment: Si estas tratando de pegar mucho codigo, entonces te dira que tenes poca explicacion y mucho codigo.. que asumo, es lo que pasa.. El ejemplo que des, debe ser minimo y explicar tu problema. mira por favor [mcve]

Comment: ahi creo que pude!

Comment: muy bien.. ahora.. que quiere decir vincular? que tratas de hacer?

Comment: mi idea es poder incluir sobre php cuando uno completa el formulario que redireccione a un html por ej de confirmacion.

Comment: actualmente cuando completo el formulario me redirecciona al mensaje incluido sobre la linea que dice echo "Mensaje enviado...." Yo lo que quiero es que redireccione a un html aparte. se entiende?

Comment: Si, se entiende, para eso debes usar `header("Location: ".$url);` donde $url representa la url que apunta a tu html. Y lo debes poner antes de cualquier "echo", sino te dará un error.

Comment: @masterguru dentro del mismo if($estadoEnvio){ ??

Comment: Sí, pero elimina o comenta los `echo` porque no van a aparecer y pueden dar problemas si intentas el `header` después de algun `echo`.

Comment: dale buenísimo! muchas gracias